# How qml MediaPlayer VideoOutput run in separate thread?

Tags: qt, qml

Suppose there is a code like this (sorry for the contrived code)

```
Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 700
    height: 700

    MediaPlayer {
        id: mediaplayer
        source: "test.avi"
        autoPlay: true
    }

    VideoOutput {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: mediaplayer
    }
    Repeater {
        id: repeater
        property int n: 1
        model: 1

        Label {
            function getRandomInt(max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max))
            }
            id: label
            y: getRandomInt(window.width)
            x: getRandomInt(window.height)
            text: "label"
        }
    }

    Timer {
        interval: 10
        running: true
        repeat: true

        onTriggered: {
            repeater.n += 1
            if (!(repeater.n % 100)) {
                repeater.model = repeater.n
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the number of labels increases, the video starts to break. How to start a video in a separate thread so that manipulations with any widgets do not interrupt it (video).

Comment: You have an XY problem, the problem has nothing to do with VideoOutput, if you replace it with another visual element and it is interactive (for example, a rectangle that changes color at every moment) you should also have the same problem. The problem itself is how to optimize Label handling with a Repeater where the model has many elements

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry for the code, I'm a newbie. But did I understand you correctly: it is not possible to separate VideoOutput into a separate thread and I only need to optimize.

Comment: VideoOutput is already optimized, and cannot be run on another thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should not overload main thread (with it's event loop). Otherwise, whole the software will lag, not only VideoOutput.
2. Don't move to another thread well-optimized and efficient controls. Move to another thread huge things, hard & long computations.

So

- avoid using timers with low interval or if you use them, don't attach to them hard things
- if you should create many or hard controls in QML, then use `Loader` or `QQmlIncubator`, they allow to create QML controls in a separate threads. Also `Loader` allows dynamically load and unload needed/unneeded controls. So, QML engine will not render too many controls, most of which even are not visible.
  Note about `Loader`/`QQmlIncubator`: they *create* control in a separate thread, not *run* it there.
- avoid writing custom properties and functions inside QML controls, place them in some single QtObject: `QtObject { id: internals; ...all your custom data... }`
- Use `ListView` instead of `Repeater`. It's more efficient because it instantiates only visible items (and several out of visible area) - **probably the most important for your sample**

More advice and samples you can find here:

- Performance Considerations And Suggestions: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html
- QML performance tips and tricks: https://katastrophos.net/harmattan-dev/html/guide/html/Developer_Library_Best_practices_for_application_development_QML_performance_tips_and_tricks.html
- QtObject: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qtobject.html